# Is applying a CSS transition on all elements a performance concern?

Tags: css

I thought it would be a nice touch to add some CSS transitions to my website so that hover affects fade in/out.  I was thinking a really simple way to do it would be with the code below:

```
a, div, input, button{

   -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    transition: background .5s;
}
```

That would make any background change fade in/out.  Of course not every a, div, input and button on my site has a background change on hover, so you won't see transitions everywhere.  But it got me wondering whether applying the transition so broadly would cause any browser performance issues, especially on phones.

So what do you think? Is it ok to implement as I have above? Or should I only apply the transition to specific elements/classes where it will apply?

Comment: Just to be safe, why not apply a class to all elements that may show transitions?  Your performance concerns are only as big as your target set of elements, and selecting those elements is dead simple.  You also have the added benefit of avoiding unexpected behavior or side effects in places you might not expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitioning certain properties, such as `left` and `margin` causes the browser to recalculate styles every frame. This can be one of the few cases where it can add noticeable weight to performance.

Other than that it is rather safe to use as many as you like, but as @SUJEET JAISWAL stated just make sure it doesn't create bad UX by going overboard too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding transition/animation on your site will add some overload to memory and/or cpu as compared to plain site, but in practice I have never find CSS transitions/animation as a performance bottleneck. So you can use them as much as you want.

But you should add them only at places it is required. Adding them unnecessarily may cause a Bad UX.

> CSS Animations , CSS Transition and
>   Javascript's requestAnimationFrame() pauses when the current tab is
>   pushed into the background.

If you are interested you should [read this article from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance)